# How to properly deploy Lambda layers with Serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to configure and deploy some layers in AWS using the Serverless framework.
The structure of the directory where the files for the layers are, is this:

```
lambda-layers
    |
    | - test-layers
         |
         | - nodejs
         |      | - index.js
         |      | - test.js
         |
         | - serverless.yml
```

My `serverless.yml` file looks like this

```
service: test-layers

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: region

layers:
  TestLayer:
    path: nodejs
```

I run `sls deploy` and I can see that the layer has been deployed, but when I try accessing functions from the files in the layer in my Lambda like this:

`const index = require('/opt/nodejs/index');`

My Lambda crashes and complains that the index module does not exist.


When I zip the layer contents and upload them manually to AWS everything works fine.



**Things that I have tried:**
- Moving `serverless.yml` inside the nodejs directory and deploying from there, but this was giving me the following error:
 `No file matches include / exclude patterns`

Answer (score 2):

Finally found out what I was doing wrong.
There is nothing wrong with the above configuration, my mistake was on requiring the files from the layers.

Instead of this:

`const index = require('/opt/nodejs/index');`

I should be doing this:

`const index = require('/opt/index');`

Comment: Accidentally came across you post after 2 hours of searching with no success. Thanks a lot.